# Remove paragraph tags from jQuery using RegEx

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to remove paragraph tags (with or without attributes) from a content using jQuery RegEx.

For example:

```
<UL><FONT face=Arial size=2><FONT face=Arial size=2><SPAN lang=EN>
<LI>List 1</LI>
<P dir=ltr align=left>
<LI>List 2</LI>
<P></P>
<P dir=ltr align=left>
<LI>List 3</LI>
<P></P></UL></FONT></FONT></SPAN>
```

must be replaced with:

```
<UL><FONT face=Arial size=2><FONT face=Arial size=2><SPAN lang=EN>
<LI>List 1</LI>
<LI>List 2</LI>
<LI>List 3</LI>
</UL></FONT></FONT></SPAN>
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: who use <font> tag nowadays?

Comment: That's awfully malformed html.

Comment: RegEx is not the right tool for the job. You should use an HTML parser, or, as Tomalak suggested, jQuery which is already a dependency. You should definitely reconsider using the above HTML at all though, it's straight from 1996. To start, the <font> tags should be replaced with proper CSS styles, and all tags should be lowercase. You should also avoid nesting tags out-of-order, e.g., `<span><p>some text</span></p>` should be `<p><span>some text</span></p>`.

Answer (score 3):

*Why on earth* do you want to use regex when you have jQuery?

```
$("ul > p").remove();
```

Comment: There is a catch... I want to remove from a given content, and not completely from the DOM, which is what "remove()" does.

Comment: Then maybe you could use [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)? Just store the affected nodes in a variable for later re-use. Or maybe `.hide()` is for you. In any case, `<p>` is not a valid child of `<ul>`. *Besides: If you would remove them via regex (God forbid) then they'd be definitely gone from the DOM, too.*

Comment: Additionally, depending on what kind of DOM the browser constructs out of the mess that is your input HTML, the simple selector (`ul > p`) might not work as anticipated. Chrome requires `ul > font > font > span > p` , other browsers maybe behave differently. You could use `ul p`, if there are no further `p` inside nested the `li` elements.